# Correct way to add request header with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes, in IE, my ajax requests do not send the header **X-Requested-With**. I searched in Google and found 2 ways to do it. Both ways seem to make sense. I want to know if there is any difference between them.

1) Using ajaxSend

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
    request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
});
```

2) Using AjaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason, use of `ajaxSetup()` is not recommended, so that leaves you with `ajaxSend()`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the full blown [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can use the headers property:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { "ResponseDataType" : "Json",
    "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"},
  // etc
});
```

Added DRY version:

```
(function (window, undefined)
{
  function extendedAjax(settings)
  {
    var defaultSettings = {
      headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" }
    };

    $.extend(defaultSettings, settings);

    var jqXHR = $.ajax(settings);

    return jqXHR;
  }

  $.extend({
    eajax: extendedAjax
  });

})(window);
```

Comment: Yes i know, but i want to do it to all Requests.

Comment: I just Extend jQuery to use all the requirements I need so my code stays [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Why not use ajaxSetup and set the headers?

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
});

Comment: I decided not to use that for three reasons.  I don't want to override 3rd-party plugs-ins that rely on AJAX having some specific values. I don't want 3rd-party plug-ins to override my Setup defaults.  Anytime I need defaults beyond what Setup allows are done in my extended version.